# Populate Highchart Line chart from live Fixer api currency data

Tags: api, highcharts

Hi I am completely new to highcharts and have a basic understanding of JavaScript.

http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key=b74dda0c99e32e39b8eb5aebaa199d1d&symbols=GBP&format=1

The following link gives access to my live JSON data.

I have created the basic chart using static data, but I am looking for the chart to read the API file instead of the static date.

Ideally the chart should update both the EUR and GBP values on a hourly basis to show the current exchange rates over a 24hour period.

The following code is my static outline

```
<body>
<div id="container"></div>
<script>
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    title: {
        text: 'Chart example'
    },
    xAxis: {


    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Pound Sterling (£)',
        data: [1.112, 1.124, 1.119, 1.121, 1.123, 1.117, 1.113]
    }, {
        name: 'Euro (€)',
        data: [1.101, 1.126, 1.112, 1.131, 1.124, 1.135, 1.101]
    }, 
    ],
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Currency Value'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle'
    },
    responsive: {
        rules: [{
            condition: {
                maxWidth: 500
            },
            chartOptions: {
                legend: {
                    layout: 'horizontal',
                    align: 'center',
                    verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                }
            }
        }]
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the actual problem is. Your API endpoint seems to only get data for a specific date. Either I'd expect an API endpoint that returned data for several dates (last month or so for example), or if you want live data at least I'd expect it to include time as well as date so the update frequency could be something less than every 24 hours. I'd expect some sort of `fetch` periodically against your API-endpoint to add points to your Highcharts series.

Comment: Hi k.angus, Additionally, here: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/live-data, you can find a very useful Highcharts atricle about working with live data.